# Проблема с отправкой POST запроса внутри приложения

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, request, google-play-services

Всем привет! На днях столкнулся с проблемой отправки post запроса на сторонний сервис с смс рассылками. Приложение загружено в google play, на всех этапах тестов(эмулятор, отладка, apk)запрос формируется и спокойно отправляется, но если установить из плеймаркета, пользователю не удаётся выполнить это

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы ответить, нужен кусок кода, который запрос направляет. По сути может быть что угодно, например аналогичный сервис Firebase проверяет токен API, который запрос формирует, а токен привязывается к приложению, при этом приложение, которое делает Google Play из APP имеет свой собственный уникальный токен, который надо брать из консоли разработчика.